# Need to modify a json list which comes under a particular value. Can you suggest me sed or awk or any linux commands?

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed, robotframework

My json list is as following:

#Input: json list#

```
[
        { 
          "Network HW Interface": "NL1A",
          "network_link": 0,
          "default": "true",
          "data": [
          {
             "switch_vlan":1001,
             "range":1
          } 
          ]
        },
        {
          "Network HW Interface": "NL1B",
          "network_link": 1,
          "data": [
          {
             "switch_vlan":2001,
             "range":1
          }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Network HW Interface": "NL2A",
          "network_link": 2,
          "data": [
          {
             "switch_vlan":3001,
             "range":1
          }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Network HW Interface": "NL2B",
          "network_link": 3,
          "data": [
          {
             "switch_vlan":4001,
             "range":1
          }
          ]
        }
]
```

I need to modify value for "switch_vlan" and "range"  under "Network HW Interface": "NL2A"  as following "switch_vlan":3005 and "range":3.Only values under that section need to be modified as shown below.

#Expected output#

```
[
        { 
          "Network HW Interface": "NL1A",
          "network_link": 0,
          "default": "true",
          "data": [
          {
             "switch_vlan":1001,
             "range":1
          } 
          ]
        },
        {
          "Network HW Interface": "NL1B",
          "network_link": 1,
          "data": [
          {
             "switch_vlan":2001,
             "range":1
          }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Network HW Interface": "NL2A",
          "network_link": 2,
          "data": [
          {
             "switch_vlan":3005,
             "range":3
          }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Network HW Interface": "NL2B",
          "network_link": 3,
          "data": [
          {
             "switch_vlan":4001,
             "range":1
          }
          ]
        }
]
```

i tried Robot framework json keywords. It didn't helped.
then tried following sed command, which is helping to replace the value, But it is affecting all similar values.

```
sed -E 's/"switch_vlan":3001,/"switch_vlan":3005/g' file.json > file1.json

sed -E 's/"range":1/"range":3/g' file1.json > file.json
```

Hence wanted something which will check for that particular field instance: "Network HW Interface": "NL2A" and will only modify the values to particular keys under that field.

Comment: Have you tried `jq`?

Comment: Yes, Tried jq as well but didn't got an example which is modifying a nested json list where the key which i need to modify is another list in the json. i have found only jq examples for json modification with single key value pair or unique key value pair. In my example, the key is not unique and also key is in another list.

Comment: The examples are there to give hints. They can't possibly be an "A to B" guide for everything people want to possibly do with information. Look at those examples and read more here and hopefully you can stitch something together that fulfills your needs. I don't have a ready answer to your question - but I suspect that with `jq` and spending a little bit of time with it, you will.

Comment: Reading your comment above (about why your first attempts to use jq didn't work) leaves me confused about what you're actually trying to do. Could you build a [mre] that factors out everything unrelated to the problem (and includes only the parts of your data that are necessary to demonstrate that a program is correctly obeying the desired constraints)?

Comment: @nanzyn The following jq command should do what you want, or at least be close enough for you to adapt it hopefully : `jq '(.[] | select(."Network HW Interface" == "NL2A") | .data[0]) = { switch_vlan: 3005, range: 3 }' file.json`.

Comment: @nanzyn Cool. Then feel free to self-answer and close your question (I can't post the answser myself for awkward reasons :)

Answer (score 0):

With sed you can select a range of lines to do substitutions.  I tested this with your data and it worked

```
sed -E '/"Network HW Interface": "NL2A"/,/\]/{
  s/"switch_vlan":3001,/"switch_vlan":3005/g
  s/"range":1/"range":3/g
}' file.json
```